# Do 50% of individuals with a history of BCC will develop another one within 5 years of diagnosis regardless of the age of the individual?

Tags: dermatology, basal-cell-carcinoma

https://skinio.com/education/basal-cell-carcinoma/ ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20201120235927/https://skinio.com/education/basal-cell-carcinoma/)) says:

> Patients diagnosed with BCC should be examined by their dermatologist at least twice a year. Remember, 50% of individuals with a history of BCC will develop another one within 5 years of diagnosis.

I wonder to what extent the age of the individual impacts this 50% statistics, since the older the individual, the more likely they are to have BCCs {1}.

Do 50% of individuals with a history of basal cell carcinoma (BCC) will develop another one within 5 years of diagnosis regardless of the age of the individual? If not, how does this number changes as their age of the individual changes? (e.g., 80% at age 70, 50% at age 60, 30% at age 50 etc.)

---

References:

- {1} [https://www.medscape.com/answers/276624-100129/how-does-the-incidence-of-basal-cell-carcinoma-bcc-vary-by-age#:~:text=The%20likelihood%20of%20developing%20BCC,mean%20age%20is%2064%20years](https://www.medscape.com/answers/276624-100129/how-does-the-incidence-of-basal-cell-carcinoma-bcc-vary-by-age#:%7E:text=The%20likelihood%20of%20developing%20BCC,mean%20age%20is%2064%20years).

  > The likelihood of developing BCC increases with age. Data indicate that BCC incidence is far higher (more than 100-fold) in persons aged 55-70 years than in those aged 20 years and younger. Patients 50-80 years of age are affected most often. The median age at diagnosis is 67 years and the mean age is 64 years.
  >
  > Nevertheless, BCC can develop in teenagers and now appears frequently in fair-skinned patients aged 30-50 years. Approximately  5% to 15% of cases of BCC occur in patients aged 20- 40 years. Aggressive-growth types of BCC are more frequently noted in patients younger than 35 years than in older individuals.

Comment: Franck, I think you're familiar enough with medical literature to know there isn't going to be an explicit answer for the way you've framed the question.

Comment: @BryanKrause I've seen many cases where age is in the x axis. My hope is that some study on BCC recurrence looked a bit more closely at the age as an independent variable.

Comment: An example of one of those "many cases" would be the obvious thing to include in your question.

Comment: @CareyGregory done, see {1}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2010 study {1} reviewed a few existing studies and seems to lean toward age as not having an impact on the recurrence rate (however, note that 1 of the reviewed studies does indicate youth+female as a risk factor of recurrence after Mohs surgery):

(NMSC = non-melanoma skin cancer, e.g. basal cell carcinoma (BCC))

> Young Age Is Not a Clinical Risk Factor
> Although young age (typically < 40 years) is generally
> viewed as a clinical risk factor for aggressive NMSC behavior, after much deliberation the panel
> decided it is not. The published biomedical literature
> does not strongly support “young age,” per se, as a
> risk factor. Leffell et al.{46} documented an increased
> percentage of basal cell cancer with aggressive histologic
> growth patterns in young persons, but this
> histologic feature is already a separate risk factor in
> the algorithm
>
> When the features of 54 basal cell cancers in
> young patients referred for Mohs surgery were compared
> with similar tumors in older patients,{47} tumor
> location, histology, and clinical morphology did not
> differ appreciably between the groups. In fact, initial
> lesion and final defect sizes were statistically smaller
> in the younger group. In a study from the United
> Kingdom in which 39 young patients with basal cell
> cancer were followed up for a minimum of 5 years,{48}
> 4 tumors were incompletely excised, 2 recurred, and
> 1 metastasized. Another study observed a higher
> number of recurrent tumors in younger women referred
> for Mohs surgery than in other demographic
> groups.{49} Finally, 2 more recent studies found no difference
> in either recurrence rates or presence of aggressive
> histologic subtypes in younger versus older
> patients with basal cell skin cancer.{50,51}
>
> The panel decided that, taken together, these
> studies do not support the suggestion that young age
> alone is a high-risk factor for NMSC behavior. Any
> tumor showing an aggressive histologic growth pattern,
> regardless of patient age, becomes a high-risk
> tumor.

---

References:

- {1} Miller SJ, Alam M, Andersen J, et al. Basal cell and squamous cell skin cancers. J Natl Compr Canc Netw 2010; 8:836. https://jnccn.org/view/journals/jnccn/8/8/article-p836.xml; DOI: https://doi.org/10.6004/jnccn.2010.0062
- {46} Leffell DJ, Headington JT, Wong DS, Swanson NA. Aggressivegrowth
  basal cell carcinoma in young adults. Arch Dermatol
  1991;127:1663–1667.
- {47} Dinehart SM, Dodge R, Stanley WE, et al. Basal cell carcinoma
  treated with Mohs surgery. A comparison of 54 younger patients
  with 1050 older patients. J Dermatol Surg Oncol 1992;18:560–566.
- {48} Cox NH. Basal cell carcinoma in young adults. Br J Dermatol
  1992;127:26–29.
- {49} Robins P, Albom MJ. Recurrent basal cell carcinomas in young
  women. J Dermatol Surg 1975;1:49–51.
- {50} Milroy CJ, Horlock N, Wilson GD, Sanders R. Aggressive basal
  cell carcinoma in young patients: fact or fiction? Br J Plast Surg
  2000;53:393–396.
- {51} Roudier-Pujol C, Auperin A, Nguyen T, et al. Basal cell carcinoma
  in young adults: not more aggressive than in older patients.
  Dermatology 1999;199:119–123.

Comment: Maybe you could accept your answer so this doesn't keep getting bumped by the system?

Comment: @CareyGregory good point, done!